# IE8 fix for background-size property? Retina Image

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, background, retina-display

I am using the following CSS for Retina images and it works perfectly in FF, Chrome, Safari but **not** in IE.

Is there a fix for IE for using background-size - and if so, how could I implement it using my current code?

**CSS:**

```
.arrow-big-right {
    display: block;
    width: 42px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 1.8em;
    background-image: url(arrow-big-right.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 42px 48px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="arrow-big-right"></div>
```

Can someone explain how I fix this for IE?

Many thanks for any help :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

IE8 and below simply [don't support `background-size`](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size) so you're either going to have to use the [AlphaImageLoader Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532969%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which has been supported since IE5.5:

```
.arrow-big-right {
    display: block;
    width: 42px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 1.8em;
    background-image: url(arrow-big-right.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 42px 48px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='arrow-big-right.png', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='arrow-big-right.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Or use some method of [targeting IE versions via CSS](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/ce7c3c5c1595ddc42ca3b961179a0cf85aa714be/index.html#L2) to apply an alternative to your background for IE8 and below users.

It's also worth noting, [as Matt McDonald points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630221/ie8-fix-for-background-size-property-retina-image/12630314?#comment-23024739), that you may see two images as a result of using this technique. This is caused by the IE filter adding a background image in addition to, instead of replacing, the standard background image. To resolve this, target IE via css using your preferred method ([here's a method, my personal favourite](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)) and remove the standard `background-image` for IE8 and below.

Using the first technique from Paul Irish's [blog post](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/) to do this, you could use the following:

```
.arrow-big-right {
    display: block;
    width: 42px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-bottom: 1.8em;
    background-image: url(arrow-big-right.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 42px 48px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='arrow-big-right.png', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader( src='arrow-big-right.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
}

.ie6 .arrow-big-right, 
.ie7 .arrow-big-right, 
.ie8 .arrow-big-right {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Comment: The AlphaImage solution sadly didn't totally work for me - I'm getting 2 images now instead of one. I think I'll load a separate stylesheet for lt IE9 and load smaller images. Thanks for the help anyways!!

Comment: If anyone else comes across this and is getting two images instead of one, you need to remove the standard background-image. Make sure you're applying your < IE9 styles in a separate file and set background-image: none before applying the MS filters.

Comment: If using this filter, I found that you can omit the -ms-filter option. Also, the URL should be relative to the HTML page and not the CSS file - I wasted a lot of time getting this to work, because I was doing it relative to CSS!

Comment: @MattMcDonald you should have written that as am answer - its more than helpful than Josh's post in its own right!

But thanks, and up vote to both of you - you really need a separate image going on here just for IE.

Comment: Thanks for this. Note: This won't work for sprites, unfortunately, but it does handle stand-alone images nicely!