# background-size not working in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

I have checked the other post. I am having some problem in using css3 property background-size in IE.

```
.topBar {
    width:100%;
    background:url(../siteImages/top_bar.png) repeat-x ;
    background-size:auto 43px;
    height:77px;
}
```

I know about this code for IE.

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

> This will make the size of background to cover the area.

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: welcome to http://stackoverflow.com :)

The background-size property is supported in IE9+, Firefox 4+, Opera, Chrome, and Safari 5+.IE 7/8 doesn't support this CSS3property

Comment: Its not working in IE9 even border-radius is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background-size` is a CSS3 property which isn't supported on IE8 and below.

You can also try this:

```
background:url(../siteImages/top_bar.png) 0 0 / auto 43px repeat-x fixed;
```

Comment: background-size is supported on IE9. Are you sure your browser is in IE9 mode? Press F12 for Developer Window.

Comment: Yes I am sure and i also checked the mode too.

Comment: Strange. It really should work, I modified my answer above. Could you please try that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for it. I changed the mode from IE9 compatibility to IE 9.Great Relief.

Comment: That's great to hear! I would be grateful if you could mark this as an answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

try to add vendor

```
/* Vendor Prefixes used with the Cover Value*/
-webkit-background-size: auto 43px;
-moz-background-size: auto 43px;
-o-background-size: auto 43px;
background-size: auto 43px;
```

also check this

[IE8 fix for background-size property? Retina Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630221/ie8-fix-for-background-size-property-retina-image)

and this

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

background-size is a CSS3 property which isn't supported before IE9.

However, there is a topic which gives possible solution: [How do I make background-size work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/how-do-i-make-background-size-work-in-ie)