# background-size on IE needs bigger than other browsers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a little problem with my background size.

On Chrome, Mozilla, even MS Edge my icon with:

```
background-size: 23px;
```

Shows nice.

But on Internet Explorer i need a:

```
background-size: 74px;
```

To get it ,to a normal look.

Whats the problem? :(

Comment: try giving background size in %

Comment: What version of IE? Background-size is CSS3. Please check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18779065/background-size-not-working-in-ie

Comment: The problem is that IE is rubbish and always has been!

Comment: @Pete but still there is people, who uses that

Comment: @KhrisRoberts IE 11.321

Comment: @AayushRohatgi the same, if I have a 63% then in IE i need about 200%

Comment: @DanielsJirgensons I know but as your question is very vague and has no way of us answering, I thought I would give a joke answer.  Please create an [MCVE] if you want to get a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! Im using .svg icons and I need to add to my svg code two things `width="" height=""` after `viewBox=""`

for example to file beginning

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_3" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 14 12.7" width="14" height="12.7" style="enable-background:new 0 0 14 12.7;" xml:space="preserve">
```

Thanks for all help :)