# CSS property background-size with ms-filer not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i didn´t know how to apply css property background-size in IE8. i found the -ms-filter is solution but how to apply exactly this code:

```
 background-size: 100% auto;
```

Thanks for any response.

This Code below still not work, can you explain me why it's not working, or give me good example. Really thanks:

```
html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../img/background.jpg');   
    background-position: left top;
    -ms-background-size: 100% auto;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    filter:   progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/background.jpg',sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/background.jpg',sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: `background-size` is not supported in IE8. This is a well-documented fact.

Comment: The best solution I'd recommend is using a decent polyfill library such as CSS3Pie which implements `background-size` (and other CSS3 features) into older IE versions.

Comment: Please take a look at here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630221/ie8-fix-for-background-size-property-retina-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Background-size is not supported in IE8 as you can see here:
http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts. I'm not a big fan of css filters.

If you would like a fullscreen background image i suggest to use one of the following solutions:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/